# If condition while joining data in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

Im tyring to write expression that

check for Column_A - If its ABCD then the join will be on DepartmentName and isActive = 1

if Column_A is other than ABCD then join will be on DepartmentCode and isActive =1

is there any way this can be accomplished in ADF

I have tried to derive nested iif statement but failing to accomplish above task

Comment: what you so far tried? and share some sample input and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use case expression in matching condition of join transformation `case(column_name=='ABCD',Department_name,Department_code)`
to achieve your requirement.

I tried to repro this with sample inputs. Below is the approach.

- Source 1 and source2 are taken as in below images respectively.

[image]
img1: Source 1 data

[image]
img2: source 2 data.

- Join transformation is added and matching condition is given as
  `case(column_name=='ABCD',Department_name,Department_code) == Department`
  (Here, inner join type is used)

[image]
img 3:  Join transformation settings

- Then filter transformation is used to filter only the records with isactive=1.

[image]
img 4: filter transformation settings.

**Output Data:**

[image]
img5: Output data after join and filter transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using split function to split data for the conditino mentioned and then finally joining it back

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).